# Javascript: "Not-A-Number" Error, with a number

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, atom-editor, nan

I am trying to do some calculations and I don't get why the functions won't return a number:

That would be the func. I am calling:

```
function prodde_kris(Stufe_Kris){
   var prodde = (20 * Math.pow(1.1, Stufe_Kris) * Stufe_Kris * bonus * ((100 + 0.66 * stufe_Plasma_1)/100) + 15)* speed; 
   return prodde;
};
```

If I hover over the function in Atom editor I get the info it will return a number, on my webbrowser Chrome they say it isn't a number.

Comment: We can't really help you if we don't know the values of all variables... Please change your code into a [mcve]. (emphasis on verifiable.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried this code. Works as per expectation with the dummy values.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="output"></h1>
<script>
    var bonus = 2.1;
    var speed = 3.4;
    var stufe_Plasma_1 = 2.3;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = prodde_kris(10);
function prodde_kris(Stufe_Kris){
   var prodde = (20 * Math.pow(1.1, Stufe_Kris) * Stufe_Kris * bonus * ((100 + 0.66 * stufe_Plasma_1)/100) + 15)* speed; 
   return prodde;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just save the above code in an HTML file and test it.

Coming to your question:
The only possibility is that either of the variable is not a number. Hence, you will need to check those values to analyse which variable is giving the output NaN.

Comment: Aah well... then someone did :)
Anyways thanks for marking it as an answer